# My type fails an enable_if predicate in a std function. Is there a way to "debug" the predicate?

Tags: c++, iterator, enable-if

My question is about `enable_if` predicates in the standard library in general, but I will frame it in the context of an iterator type, as that is where I am currently running into this issue.

I have a custom iterator type `It`, such that `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` is `Val`. I've been using this type successfully with a pre-C++11 standard, but now with C++11 (and in another, generally stricter compiler) compilation is failing. One of the use cases I have is to [insert into a vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) like

```
std::vector<Val> v; 
It begin = ...
It end = ...   
v.insert(v.end(), begin, end);
```

the compiler's reason for rejecting the particular overload candidate `insert<_Iter>(iterator, _Iter, _Iter)` that I wanted is:

```
no matching member function for call to 'insert'
candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Iter = It]
```

Looking into the `<vector>` header, I see that the failing `enable_if` predicate is `_Is_Iterator`. Is there a way to step through the predicate conditions to find out which one `It` is not fulfilling, or generally any way to find out this information without needing to manually check all the requirements of `InputIterator` (or whatever the relevant concept may be) one by one?

The old compiler (for which `It` works) is `bcc32` from C++ Builder XE8; the new compiler is the Clang-based 32-bit compiler in C++ Builder 10.1.

Comment: Maybe [templight](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/templight) can help with that.

Comment: Looks good. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @alcedine With sites such as [encppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), it is pretty easy to check the requirements for any concept one by one.

Comment: @Holt It's not so much that it's difficult, it's that there can be quite a lot of it to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler will attempt to tell you which parameter is wrong. Visual Studio, will tell you the overload that most closely matched your specifications and which parameters matched or didn't match. I believe that Clang and gcc do that as well.

Once you've read the parameter that doesn't match, it's your responsibility to determine if the compiler tried the right overload, and how your parameter failed to match.

In most cases this is pretty straight forward. But you're right for iterators it can be a bit daunting. But that's why this is generally handled by inheritance from [`iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) by your boilerplate.

When you're writing an iterator it's your responsibility to implement the requirements of the iterator category that you inherited from.

[`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) requires the last two parameters to be "[InputIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)". So you should have inherited from `iterator<input_iterator_tag, T>` or one of the more strenuous tags. An "InputIterator" is defined as:

1. A type that satisfies all requirements of an "[Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator)"
2. A type that is "[EquallyComparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable)"
3. The `reference` and `value_type` member types are defined
4. The inequality operator is defined
5. The pointer dereference and member selection operators are defined
6. The pre-increment and post-increment operators are defined

Comment: I'm afraid this is not an answer to the question I was asking.

Comment: @alcedine You're failing `vector`'s `enable_if` and you want to step through the requirements for an "InputIterator", right? These are the requirements. Or have I misunderstood what you're asking?

Comment: I meant stepping through them somewhat like you would step through code in a debugger, or just getting some more specific error information (as in, "`It` does not satisfy condition X of C", not just "`It` does not satisfy C") -- not checking them manually from a list. Apologies if this was not clear.

Comment: @alcedine I've updated my answer. I'm sure that you're not asking about a third party suggestion, (as http:://stackoverflow.com prohibits such questions.) So your official answer is: "No, there isn't a way" But most compilers do a good job for almost everything but iterators. And for iterators the standard provides you a ton of help, are you using that help?

Comment: Well, you've expanded on overload resolution here, but that much was always clear. I know which overload of `insert` I'm looking for, and I know from the compiler output what reason the compiler had for rejecting that overload candidate (see the output I posted; the candidate was disabled by `enable_if`).

Comment: @alcedine Yup. The compiler is the only one who knows where your type has failed. It'll give you the `enable_if` line, so you can go look at the actual code and see what was needed that failed. But this is still gonna be higher level than you want, but since the compiler is the only one that knows and it's already given you everything it has on the issue your key takeaway is: "In most cases this is pretty straight forward. But you're right for iterators it can be a bit daunting. But that's why this is generally handled by inheritance from `iterator` by your boilerplate."